# FFMPEG: Adding and muting audio streams using filter_complex

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

This command works flawlessly for adding short audio clips to video:

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -i 3.mp3 -i 4.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -i 5.mp3 -i 4.mp3 \
  -filter_complex " \
    [1]adelay=0[b]; \
    [2]adelay=13000[c]; \
    [3]adelay=23000[d]; \
    [4]adelay=37000[e]; \
    [5]adelay=47000[f]; \
    [0][b][c][d][e][f]amix=6" \
output.mp4
```

But this way mp3s are just overlayed onto the original audio track from video.
How do I completely mute video during those audio clips?

Answer (score 0):

for muting video's audio when other audio's are playing you can do this :

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -i 3.mp3 -i 4.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -i 5.mp3 -i 4.mp3 \
      -filter_complex " \
         [0]volume=enable=between(t,MuteStartTimeHere,MuteEndTimeHere):volume=0;
         [2]adelay=13000[c]; \
            [3]adelay=23000[d]; \
            [4]adelay=37000[e]; \
            [5]adelay=47000[f]; \
            [0][c][d][e][f]amix=6" \
        output.mp4
```

If you don't want video just want all audios then save output file by `.mp3`

If you want video of first input but don't want it's audio then .

```
    ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -i 3.mp3 -i 4.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -i 5.mp3 -i 4.mp3 \
  -filter_complex " \
     [2]adelay=13000[c]; \
        [3]adelay=23000[d]; \
        [4]adelay=37000[e]; \
        [5]adelay=47000[f]; \
        [b][c][d][e][f]amix=6[z]" -map "[z]" -map 0:v\
    output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you! What about multiple MuteStartTimes and MuteEndTimes in one command? Each of audio clips are 1-2 seconds long. So after muting for e.g. 2 sec I want to unmute back to the original sound track from mp4, then mute it, play mp3 and unmute again, etc.

Comment: write a program. or use `[0]volume=enable=between(t,3,5):volume=0; `  `[0]volume=enable=between(t,10,20):volume=0; ` **multiple** times.

Comment: why `ffmpeg -i M:\Sounds\00\00\00\32\05.mp2 -i M:\Sounds\00\00\00\36\71.mp2 -i M:\Sounds\00\00\00\40\60.mp2 -i M:\Sounds\00\00\00\36\71.mp2 -filter_complex "[0]adelay=delays=0:all=1[a0]; [1]adelay=delays=3239:all=1[a1]; [2]adelay=delays=118543:all=1[a2]; [0]volume=enable=between(t,118543,124521):volume=0[a0]; [3]adelay=delays=124521:all=1[a3]; [a0][a1][a2][a3]amix=inputs=4" -t 240325ms output.wav` return to me this error `Error initializing filter 'volume' with args 'enable=between(t'
Error initializing complex filters.`